# QT SQLite not working in Embedded device

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QT framework. Basically I am creating application for ARM devices.

Now I've created sample application using SQLite for DB work. Thing is that one is working in my desktop but when I cross compiled it for device and tried to execute it in my device Getting error.

So I logged some error messages. Finally i found that DB file was created successfully but unable to create table in device.

Is it because of out of memory issue?

Code :

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("songs.db");
    if (!db.open()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, qApp->tr("Cannot open database"),
            qApp->tr("Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                     "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                     "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information how "
                     "to build it.\n\n"
                     "Click Cancel to exit."), QMessageBox::Cancel);
        //return false;

debugLog("#fileListThread::run()-> Unable to establish a database connection.."<<db.lastError(););
                }
else
{
    debugLog("#fileListThread::run()-> opened songs.db successfully..");
}

QSqlQuery query;


bool queryStatus = query.exec("create table songsList (id int primary key, "
           "Song varchar(20), Artist varchar(20),Producer varchar(20))");

if(queryStatus)
{
    debugLog("#fileListThread::run()-> created table in songs DB successfully..");
}
else
{
    debugLog("#fileListThread::run()-> failed to create table in songs DB.."<<query.lastError(););
}
```

Okay! One more quick question-> Is it possible to create DB file and executing queries inside in embeedded devices. In my device available free memory is 9MB.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Comment: Improve your error handling code, at least log or display the value of QSqlDatabase.lastError().number.  The more the merrier.

Comment: Thanks! let me try it and will post the error number if possible

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songsList
```

sql statement rather than

```
create table songsList
```

Otherwise once the table is created , the second time you try to execute it, you may get an error.

Other than that I don't see a problem but who knows... I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay! thanks for your answer! Let me try that. One more quick question-> Is it possible to create DB file and executing queries inside in embeedded devices. In my device available free memory is 9MB.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178264/sqlite-on-an-embedded-system . It seems it is possible.

Comment: code:   debugLog("#fileListThread::run()-> failed to create table in songs DB.."<<query.lastError(););

Comment: What you wrote is correct but he won't get errors if he omits "IF NOT EXISTS"