# SQLite on bare hardware

Tags: sql, sqlite, embedded

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sqlite on an embedded system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178264/sqlite-on-an-embedded-system)

I'm trying to make SQL lite run on a powerpc architecture (MPC565 memory-36K) where I do not have any OS. 
I saw that SQL lite requires libraries like mmap.h that are not available in my environment. Is  there anyone that managed to port SQL lite  without using libraries like mmap.h. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178264/sqlite-on-an-embedded-system

Comment: SQLLite weighs in at about 275Kb of code space; is the 36K you refer to just RAM?  That is remarkably small for a PowerPC based system. How much code space?  And where is the data itself going to reside, let alone an application to use it?  Perhaps you are confused by the term "embedded database"?  In the context of SQLLite it refers to a database engine that is embeddable in an application, not necessarily one suitable for use in embedded-systems.  See the first paragraph of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database.